# SQL: Including Null values with Outer Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using this query, my output includes all values where COUNT is 0, but I still get the warning that Null values have been not been included. The double joins are to get the tables linked appropriately to count the number of orders, but I want to include all NULL as well, not just where COUNT is 0. What am I missing?

```
SELECT EmpNo, LastName, COUNT(CustomerOrder.OrderNo)
FROM Employee 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer
    ON Customer.AcctRepNo = EmpNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerOrder
    ON Customer.CustNo =CustomerOrder.CustNo 
GROUP BY EmpNo, LastName
ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerOrder.OrderNo) DESC, LastName
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: And ***exactly*** what warnign are you receiving?  And exactly what do you mean by `but I want to include all NULL as well`?

Comment: "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

Comment: Personally, I'd probably do something like `LEFT JOIN (Customer JOIN CustomerOrder ON ...) ON ... ` (because you care about the set of rows generated by that).  Heck, I'd probably make the join of those two tables a CTE, then left-join to the CTE (since your RDBMS supports it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are fine, it is including all your values. The message it's only saying that when the column `CustomerOrder.OrderNo` is null, then it is not counting them (hence, the count value of zero).